# Event propagation in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2

If I have a widget that fires a custom event, and that widget is contained in a hierarchy of other widgets like:

```
Parent1 contains Parent2 contains Parent3 contains CustomWidget
```

Then in order to propagate the initial event to Parent1, do i have to add event handlers all over the way and make each interior node fire the same event, or there is another way?

Let's say we have the following custom widget1:

```
<g:FocusPanel>

 <g:Image/>

</g:FocusPanel>
```

And it is contained in custom widget2 which listens for events fired by widget1:

```
<g:ScrollPanel>

 <my:CustomWidget1/>

</g:ScrollPanel>
```

Now, if custom widget2 is itself contained to another widget (and in turn is contained to another...) then in order to catch the first event dispatched from widget1 do i have to add handlers respectively to all parent widgets, or there is another way?

Comment: Please add some code - Should be easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT suggest to use an EventBus for handling such events.

See [Google I/O 2009 - Best Practices for Architecting GWT App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM)

See Google I/O 2009 - Best Practices for Architecting GWT App  (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM)